# How do I save a data without customer input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5

Right now, I have a table named "API" with two column which are "name" and "status".

I create a form_for in my template and customer can input "name" and "status" then save to my database.

I want to ask how do only input "name" and "status" alway be same value?
For example, custom input "logout" for name and I lock "good" for status.

Comment: please ellaborate more

Comment: do you want a placeholder value on the form, or do you want to store it as logout and good always?

Comment: I want store the value always not placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to set default value to the form input. You could do it by

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :value => 'Logout' %>
<%= f.text_field :status, :value => 'Good' %>
```

Comment: Is this for simple_form? because I am not using simple_form and get "undefined method 'input' " error

Comment: Could you paste your code in the question? It would be helpful for debugging.